# Promise.all: What are arguments of promise.all.catch(e)

Tags: javascript

What are arguments of promise.all.catch(e)

Is e an array of errors or object?

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, ..])
.then((result1, result2,..)=>{})
.catch((error1,error2..???)=>{

})
```

How can we get array of errors? if not Promise.all then how?

Comment: can we get errors from all promises?

Answer (score 1):

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.all)

> **The all function returns a new promise** which is fulfilled with an
> array of fulfillment values for the passed promises, or **rejects with
> the reason of the first passed promise that rejects**. It resolves all
> elements of the passed iterable to promises as it runs this algorithm.

Hence [promise.catch](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.prototype.catch)

> When the catch method is called with argument onRejected the following
> steps are taken:
>
> - Let promise be the this value.
> - Return Invoke(promise, "then", «‍undefined, onRejected»).

Hence **reason of the first passed promise that rejects** is the argument of `promise.all.catch`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between an error handling of a simple `Promise` and a `Promise.all`.

Which means :

```
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, ...])
  .then((v) => {
     // ...
  })
  .catch((err) => {
     // ...
  });
```

With one error in the catch.

---

`Promise.all` return in an array (in the then) all results of given `Promises`.

In case of error it **throw** the error, that you **catch** (1 error).

---

---

**EDIT** :
**About the fact to get all errors which seems to be the real question here**

Javascript is single threaded, which means that it can execute only one function at a time. Javascript asynchronism means only that I/O won't be blocking.

The way Promise.all work is that at the first encountered error, it throw. And stop other promises. So **you cannot have multiple errors**.

Comment: I need to get all errors. Can we use anything other than Promise.all then?

Comment: @ShishirArora I have edited my answer

Comment: My question seems duplicate. I saw good answers there. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to accomplish requires a different approach:

```
const promises = [p1, p2];

const promisesWithExceptionInfo = promises.map(p => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    p.then(result => resolve({result})).catch(error => resolve({error})); 
  });
});

// now your promises will always be resolved but contain either a result or an error

Promise.all(promisesWithExceptionInfo).then(res => {
  // res is an array of objects where each promise result or error can be evaluated
});
```